# Differences Calling SOAP Methods Between Servers

Tags: web-services, url, soap

I'm porting a C# .NET SOAP application from one server to a new one. On the original server I can pass the URL `http://oldserver.com/myapp.asmx/method1` and it returns  an XML file with the result.

On the new server this doesn't work. It replies with `500 Internal Server Error`. The SOAP interface is working because I can call the same method on the new server using an Python application using urllib2 and suds.

How do I implement the same behaviour on the new server? We have a product that checks for updates using the URL based SOAP request, so the new server must be able to do that as well to be backward compatible with products in the field.

Is it possible that the old server somehow translates the URL into a SOAP request internally before passing it on to the application? Unfortunately I only have ftp access to the old server. The HTTP headers tell me that I am talking to `Microsoft-IIS/6.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was in the web.config file. The old server contained:

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```

That seems to enable invoking URL based methods.